How to Display the ListView at the Bottom Directly When Opening a Chat Page (Like Most Chat Apps)?
I'm building a Chat Page and want it to display the latest message when opened, similar to most chat apps. Currently, I have tried two approach.
Approach 1. Using addPostFrameCallback with jumpTo like this, but this will causes the screen flicker when opened.
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((\_) {

  provider.chatScrollController.jumpTo(

  provider.chatScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);

});

Approach 2. Using `reverse: true` but this will display the message at the bottom when there only one or two.
is there a better way to achieve smooth scrolling to the latest message without the flicker? Would love any advice or suggestions!

You can use animateTo method from ScrollController. In your code change jumpTo to animateTo then add duration and curves properties inside the method like this:
// Make sure the widget is already rendered.
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // Move the scroll position to the bottom of the page with animation.
  provider.chatScrollController.animateTo(
    provider.chatScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    // [duration] for setting the animation duration. 
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    // [curve] An parametric animation easing curve, i.e. a mapping of the unit 
    // interval to the unit interval.
    // (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curve-class.html)
    // 
    // In simple term is to manage how your animation run.
    curve: Curves.fastEaseInToSlowEaseOut,
  );
});

This will animating your scroll to the bottom of the page.
Reference animateTo Flutter Documentation

You can achieve this by using a SingleChildScrollView with the reverse property set to true. Then, wrap it with an Align widget and set alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, like so:
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  reverse: true,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        // Your widgets go here
      ],
    ),
  ),
),

